# How to replace first # with ? in querystring and then forward to server, with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

my browser is receiving a # in a redirect url instead of a ? ie:

```
localhost/endpoint#code=12345
```

However everything after # gets removed before the server endpoint is called. Theerfore I need to replace the # with a ? to ensure that the querystring gets to the server.

How can I achieve this in the browser, using JS?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Just a few more thoughts on how the calls are made:

1) Call made 3rd party Identity Server endpoint

2) 3rd party Identity Server then redirects back, via browser, with provided URL ie localhost/endpoint with payload ie code=12345 usually ?code=12345 but in this case #code=12345 so full URL is localhost/endpoint#code=12345

3) At present localhost/endpoint gets sent back to server as everything post # gets stripped off, hence this question as to how I can correct localhost/endpoint#code=12345 to be localhost/endpoint?code=12345 and then forward to server

I am sorry about the down points, but I am limited here with my options

Comment: Maybe you should fix whatever page that is making that malformed request, because that's not a valid query string to begin with? This feels like a dirty hack/fix instead of solving the root of the issue.

Comment: @Terry `#` is often used for front end queries. While technically not valid, they serve a purpose and are often used.

Comment: @MauriceNino `#` is perfectly "technically valid." It separates the fragment identifier from the rest of the URL. Which is why it's an error that this URL is being used for information that needs to be sent to the server: fragment identifiers aren't sent to the server.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder That's what I meant. With "technically not valid" I meant that it is not usable for that purpose. Also, it does not mean that there is an error. Might be that the author got this URL from some front end code, which was not intended for back end use (probably, because otherwise he would not have to transform it) and therefore it is not a bug, but an unintended use case.

Comment: I know this may seem hacky. This redirect is coming from a 3rd party OAUTH2 identity server which I cannot change, so I have what I have.

Comment: Then you need to parse the url hash and store the code value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `var fixedUrl = yourUrl.replace("#","?")`

to forward inbound url, use `location.href`. Rude ducttape fix would be

```
if(location.hash.indexOf("=")>0) location.href.replace("#","?");
```

Comment: How do I capture inbound URL? Also how do I automatically reforward to the corrected URL.

Comment: @SamJolly yes, see [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Comment: Just struggling with this, especially around the flow which I understand as: 1. Inbound URL goes into Location box. 2) Call made to server 3) Server processes data 4) Server returns page when JS runs. But I need to do this replace before 2) when the page is not even loaded. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: @SamJolly you can do it in inline javascript which is executed before the external content (styles, images, scripts) is loaded. As soon as you change location.href object, redirect is performed. If you want to change it as soon as the http header is loaded (before http contents), front-end javascript can not do that, you need to solve it on proxy server or via browser extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace if I understand you correctly.

```
const url = "localhost/endpoint#code=12345";

const newUrl = url.replace('#', '?'); // Replace # with ?
```

More information can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: It will replace every # to ?.  What can be another solution?

Comment: It will not replace every #. Using replace will only replace the first instance of the character you specify unless you use a regex